# my OpenGL program small error, really need help

Tags: opengl

```
//
// This code was created by Jeff Molofee '99
//
// If you've found this code useful, please let me know.
//
// Visit me at www.demonews.com/hosted/nehe
//
/**************************************************************/
// This code was ported to MacOS by Tony Parker.
//  I'd also appreciate it if you could drop me a line if you found
//  this code useful. 
// 
//  Tony Parker - asp@usc.edu
// 
// Have a nice day.

#include <stdio.h>          // Header File For Standard Input / Output
#include <stdarg.h>         // Header File For Variable Argument Routines
#include <string.h>         // Header File For String Management
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>              // Header File For The OpenGL32 Library
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>         // Header File For The GLu32 Library
#include <GLUT/glut.h>          // Header File For The GLUT Library

// Constants -----------------------------------------------------------------

#define kWindowWidth    512
#define kWindowHeight   256

// Structures ----------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct              // Create A Structure
{
    GLubyte *imageData;     // Image Data (Up To 32 Bits)
    GLuint  bpp;            // Image Color Depth In Bits Per Pixel.
    GLuint  width;          // Image Width
    GLuint  height;         // Image Height
    GLuint  texID;          // Texture ID Used To Select A Texture
} TextureImage;             // Structure Name

// Function Prototypes -------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid InitGL(GLvoid);
GLvoid DrawGLScene(GLvoid);
GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(int Width, int Height);
GLvoid Idle(GLvoid);
bool LoadTGA(TextureImage *texture, char *filename);
GLvoid LoadGLTextures(GLvoid);

// Global Variables ----------------------------------------------------------

TextureImage    texture[1];     // Texture Storage ( NEW )

GLfloat         xrot;           // X Rotation ( NEW )
GLfloat         yrot;           // Y Rotation ( NEW )
GLfloat         zrot;           // Z Rotation ( NEW )

// Main ----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(kWindowWidth, kWindowHeight); 
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

    InitGL();

    glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLScene); 
    glutReshapeFunc(ReSizeGLScene);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);

    xrot = 0;
    yrot = 0;       
    zrot = 0;

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

// InitGL --------------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid InitGL(GLvoid)
{

    LoadGLTextures();                           // Load The Texture(s) ( NEW )
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                    // Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);       // This Will Clear The Background Color To Black
    glClearDepth(1.0);                          // Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);                       // The Type Of Depth Test To Do
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                    // Enables Depth Testing 
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                    // Enables Smooth Color Shading

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();                           // Reset The Projection Matrix

    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat) kWindowWidth / (GLfloat) kWindowHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);  
    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

// Idle ----------------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid Idle(GLvoid)
{
    xrot += 0.3f;           // X Axis Rotation
    yrot += 0.2f;           // Y Axis Rotation
    zrot += 0.4f;           // Z Axis Rotation

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// DrawGLScene ---------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid DrawGLScene(GLvoid)
{    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);

    glRotatef(xrot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);             // Rotate On The X Axis
    glRotatef(yrot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);             // Rotate On The Y Axis
    glRotatef(zrot,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);             // Rotate On The Z Axis

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0].texID);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Front Face
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    // Back Face
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    // Top Face
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    // Bottom Face
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    // Right face
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    // Left Face
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glEnd();



    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

// ReSizeGLScene ------------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(int Width, int Height)
{
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) Width, (GLsizei) Height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0, (GLfloat) Width / (GLfloat) Height, 0.1, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

// LoadGLTextures ----------------------------------------------------------

GLvoid LoadGLTextures(GLvoid)
{
    LoadTGA(texture, "NeHe.tga");
}

/********************> LoadTGA() <*****/
bool LoadTGA(TextureImage *texture, char *filename)         // Loads A TGA File Into Memory
{    
    GLubyte     TGAheader[12]={0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};    // Uncompressed TGA Header
    GLubyte     TGAcompare[12];                             // Used To Compare TGA Header
    GLubyte     header[6];                                  // First 6 Useful Bytes From The Header
    GLuint      bytesPerPixel;                              // Holds Number Of Bytes Per Pixel Used In The TGA File
    GLuint      imageSize;                                  // Used To Store The Image Size When Setting Aside Ram
    GLuint      temp;                                       // Temporary Variable
    GLuint      type=GL_RGBA;                               // Set The Default GL Mode To RBGA (32 BPP)

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");                     // Open The TGA File

    if( file==NULL ||                                       // Does File Even Exist?
       fread(TGAcompare,1,sizeof(TGAcompare),file)!=sizeof(TGAcompare) ||   // Are There 12 Bytes To Read?
       memcmp(TGAheader,TGAcompare,sizeof(TGAheader))!=0                ||  // Does The Header Match What We Want?
       fread(header,1,sizeof(header),file)!=sizeof(header))             // If So Read Next 6 Header Bytes
    {
        fclose(file);                                       // If Anything Failed, Close The File
        return false;                                       // Return False
    }

    texture->width  = header[1] * 256 + header[0];          // Determine The TGA Width  (highbyte*256+lowbyte)
    texture->height = header[3] * 256 + header[2];          // Determine The TGA Height (highbyte*256+lowbyte)

    if( texture->width  <=0 ||                              // Is The Width Less Than Or Equal To Zero
       texture->height  <=0 ||                              // Is The Height Less Than Or Equal To Zero
       (header[4]!=24 && header[4]!=32))                    // Is The TGA 24 or 32 Bit?
    {
        fclose(file);                                       // If Anything Failed, Close The File
        return false;                                       // Return False
    }

    texture->bpp    = header[4];                            // Grab The TGA's Bits Per Pixel (24 or 32)
    bytesPerPixel   = texture->bpp/8;                       // Divide By 8 To Get The Bytes Per Pixel
    imageSize       = texture->width*texture->height*bytesPerPixel; // Calculate The Memory Required For The TGA Data

    texture->imageData=(GLubyte *)malloc(imageSize);        // Reserve Memory To Hold The TGA Data

    if( texture->imageData==NULL ||                         // Does The Storage Memory Exist?
       fread(texture->imageData, 1, imageSize, file)!=imageSize)    // Does The Image Size Match The Memory Reserved?
    {
        if(texture->imageData!=NULL)                        // Was Image Data Loaded
            free(texture->imageData);                       // If So, Release The Image Data

        fclose(file);                                       // Close The File
        return false;                                       // Return False
    }

    for(GLuint i=0; i<int(imageSize); i+=bytesPerPixel)     // Loop Through The Image Data
    {                                                       // Swaps The 1st And 3rd Bytes ('R'ed and 'B'lue)
        temp=texture->imageData[i];                         // Temporarily Store The Value At Image Data 'i'
        texture->imageData[i] = texture->imageData[i + 2];  // Set The 1st Byte To The Value Of The 3rd Byte
        texture->imageData[i + 2] = temp;                   // Set The 3rd Byte To The Value In 'temp' (1st Byte Value)
    }

    fclose (file);                                          // Close The File

    // Build A Texture From The Data
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0].texID);                    // Generate OpenGL texture IDs

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0].texID);         // Bind Our Texture
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   // Linear Filtered
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   // Linear Filtered

    if (texture[0].bpp==24)                                 // Was The TGA 24 Bits
    {
        type=GL_RGB;                                        // If So Set The 'type' To GL_RGB
    }

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, type, texture[0].width, texture[0].height, 0, type, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[0].imageData);

    return true;                                            // Texture Building Went Ok, Return True
}
```

IN LINE 47, and 194 I got

> "/Users/mbp/Desktop/XcodeGLUT/main.c:47:0
>   /Users/mbp/Desktop/XcodeGLUT/main.c:47:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm'
>   or '**attribute**' before 'LoadTGA'
>
> "

I really cannot find anything wrong here..Can anybody help me.

Comment: Are you compiling it in C++ or C? Also, try #undef bool before the first error line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `#include <stdbool.h>` under `#include <stdlib.h>`